# Why vectors change under boost along some axis?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

I was trying to solve this problem :

> Give the Lorentz transformations for the components $a_μ$ of a vector under a boost along the $x_1$ axis.

I understood that due to relativistic effects some vector quantities, say velocity is represented in a different tuple viewed from another Lorenz frame , say moving along the x axis. But I think this is inherently due to the nature of velocity being rate of change of position. The question asks for any vector and I can't understand why would arbitrary vectors also change under transformations?

One possibility is representation would change , say under rotation, but vector itself is still the same thing. But even in this case how does time come into play?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the greek subscript on the vector implies (by convention) that it is a 4-vector, which has a variety of representations (lexically, not group theory):

$$ a_{\mu} = (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3) $$
$$ a_{\mu} = (a_t, a_x, a_y, a_z) $$
$$ a_{\mu} = (a_0, a_i)\ \ i\in (1,2,3) $$
$$ a_{\mu} = (a_0, \vec a) $$

where the latin subscripts indicate a Euclidean 3-vector, as does the arrow.

You can apply a Lorentz transform to those in the standard fashion.

The key point is that the 4-velocity differs from the 3-velocity ($\vec v$):

$$ u_{\mu} = (\gamma c, \gamma \vec{v}) $$

Note that the space part (subscripts $(1,2,3)$ or $(x, y, z)$) differs from the usual 3-velocity by a factor of $\gamma$.

This is the object that transforms conversantly under Lorentz transformations.

Other 4-vectors are related to it, such as: the momentum of a particle:

$$ p_{\mu} = mu_{\mu} = (\gamma mc, \gamma m\vec v) = (E/c, \vec p)$$

or the current of a charge:

$$ j_{\mu} = qu_{\mu} $$

Comment: yeah, but what i didn't get is why we can apply the transform in the standard fashion? Momentum is relativistic, so is charge but arbitrary 4-vectors are as well?

Comment: the whole point of 4 vectors is that they transform under a representation of the Lorentz group.